# HTML EMBED tag (pdf or txt) preview image like google drive

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a project where i want to display files like google drive.
I want to display a preview or placeholder image in a div from a PDF or a TXT file like google drive does.

Here is how a txt looks on google drive:

[image]

They actually have an image in here. Do they extract it in the backend? How do google does it?

If i create an embed tag like this:

```
<div class="file txt">
    <div class="fileImgWrap">
        <embed src="driveSpace/test.txt" type="text/html" class="fileTxt"></embed>
    </div>
    <div class="fileInfo">
       <div class="fileIco">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-file-lines"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="fileName">Egy txt 1</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Or a pdf they look like this:

[image]

**css properties like overflow:hidden or background-color:white is not affecting these embeds.**

I searched the web in order to style these embedded contents in order to modify my embedded txt file's background color or make the overflow dissappear but couldn't find any usefull information.

I hope someone can help me in any of these.

EDIT WITH EXAMPLE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Main</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a26f6e4ee4.js"></script>
<style>
.files{
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.file {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.file:hover .fileInfo{
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

.fileImgWrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

.fileInfo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    color: #708089;
}

img.fileImg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.filePdf,.fileTxt{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; // Nothing works other then height and width.
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="files">
  <div class="file image">
    <div class="fileImgWrap">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653164731406-d0406fcef4dd?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NTU3Mzk1NzQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80" alt="" class="fileImg">
    </div>
    <div class="fileInfo">
      <div class="fileIco">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-image"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="fileName">A Photo</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="file pdf">
    <div class="fileImgWrap">
      <embed src="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" class="filePdf"></embed>
    </div>
    <div class="fileInfo">
      <div class="fileIco">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="fileName">A pdf 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="file txt">
    <div class="fileImgWrap">
      <embed src="test.txt" style="background-color:white;" type="text/html" class="fileTxt"></embed>
    </div>
    <div class="fileInfo">
      <div class="fileIco">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-file-lines"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="fileName">A txt 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My main goal is to take a thumbnail from the content of the pdf and txt files to be able to display it like an image.

I have tried with iframe with the following script:

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        iframes[i].onload = function() {
            console.log("IFrame loaded: " + this.src);
            this.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
    }
```

And with embed

```
let allTxtFiles = document.querySelectorAll('.fileTxt');
        for (const file of allTxtFiles) {
            file.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            file.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            file.style.color = 'black';
        }
```

**The only solution where i can partially manipulate ONLY TXT IFRAMES is with a js onload and contentwindow like this:**

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].onload = function() {
        let stylesToAdd = `overflow:hidden;background-color:#afbcc3;border:none;color:#37474f;`;
        this.contentWindow.document.body.style.cssText = stylesToAdd;
    }
}
```

*This works only on txt iframes and not on pdfs.And it still not an image of the file content but a style to it which kinda looks like crap*

Answer (score 1):

```
<embed style="width:100px;height:50px;background-color:red;" src="test.txt" type="text/plain">
</embed>
```

This works for me an shows the given text file with red background. may be you can create a working jsfiddle with links to your files. i dont think that changing the background color will work for pdf, as pdf defines a page color and a plain text file does not.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it wasn't too helpful. I can not create a jsfiddle since it requires a file to be loaded from server side. But i edit my post and i create a working example. Inline styles does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

3rd answer on the same question. new record. achievement unlocked. read the f**** question more carefully.

I think googledocs create the preview images serverside. thats something different then embedding a file, which (of course) uses the hole file and therefore the scrollbars. If you create a preview image of the content then you have control how the image looks like - f.e. image dimensions, background-color, font, font-color, etc.

For image creation you probably need a server side language, php for example. with php you can create an image on the fly `imagecreatetruecolor`, set a background color `imagefill`, read the content of the textfile `file_get_contents` and draw the content to the image `imagestring` then create the desired format `imagejpeg` for example (you should save the image instead of recreating it every time) and then finally release the image resources with `imagedestoy`.

For a textfile that will be rather easy, for another image probably too, but pdf might get more tricky, dont know if php supports pdf out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your commnet. Yes, the answers are all focused to embed or iframe elements, but what i really want to achive is the same thing as google drive does with the file to image thingy. Thank you for the PHP answer, i did not specify what backend i use, hovewer you did give me some idea where to look at. I'm using NodeJS as the backend, and now i can search for similar approaches like PHP does. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow is applied to the root document (your html file) and therefore has no effect on the embedded document (the text or pdf file). you can check this by opening the dom inspector of your browser, select the embedded tag with the text-file, expanding the nodes below #document and select the body element - then add the overflow style to it.
that works. but from what i've read, there is no way to access or style the document that is generated for the embedded document. but you can try the following.

You can try the following:

1. Use an iframe instead.
2. give the iframe a unique id, lets say 'x'
3. add a javascript to your page
4. add an onload listener to the iframe
5. after the document has been loaded, use `document.getElementById('x').contentDocument.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';` to style the loaded document.
6. This will work only with content that comes from the same origin for security reasons

And the last point is the reason why i cant test it. Looks like browsers treat local opened files from the same directory NOT as same origin...

Comment: I have tried this way:

let allTxtFiles = document.querySelectorAll('.fileTxt');
        for (const file of allTxtFiles) {
            // add overflow:hidden
            file.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            // add bg-color white
            file.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            // add color black
            file.style.color = 'black';
        }

Does not work

Comment: I frame does not work

Comment: Does not work either:

var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
            iframes[i].onload = function() {
                console.log("IFrame loaded: " + this.src);
                this.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

A browser and its settings are the users domain, yours is public domain serving, thus can attempt to influence but not control. Here I can chose what happens when the HTML has been view after download. So yes you can set a color preference e.g. magenta, for iFrame (upper two samples of PDf and text) or embed (lower two samples of PDf and text)

Note Chrome Edge and Firefox use totally different approaches to background, also note I can block iFrame pdf content (or allow same as embed) and can allow the embed under my full foreground and background colour control.

For the text background color it is down to the user choice of browser, simply tell Chromium users to switch to Mozilla.

Chromium on Left Firefox on Right
[image]